# Stuck in a PostgreSQL search query

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
I have 3 tables:

1. users
-- _id
-- firstname

3. roles
-- _id
-- user_id
-- alias // admin, hr etc..

2. userroles
-- user_id
-- role_id
```

Here is the query I tried.

```
SELECT u._id, u.firstname, u.lastname, array_agg(r.alias) as roles
FROM users u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN userroles ur ON (u._id = ur.user_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN roles r ON (ur.role_id = r._id)
GROUP BY u._id
HAVING u.firstname='Admin' AND array_agg(r.alias) @> '{"ad", "gm"}'
```

I want to query users who have multiple roles within the given roles. For example, Only users who are either `admin` or `hr`. The current query only matches exact roles and not multiple roles. Can you suggest something??

Comment: i didn't know PostgreSQL supported ANSI/ISO SQL 2003 optional functional dependency feature?  Can you post the `CREATE TABLE` structures?

Comment: @RaymondNijland It does, as Postgres is closest to the ANSI standard.  But, it only supports it if legitimate (i.e. broken only full group by MySQL queries would not run).

Comment: @RaymondNijland SQL Server does not support it, nor does Oracle (AFAIK).  It's nice to have, though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  yes i would have expected some documentation about that feature.. I never read it was possible. as *"T301 Functional dependencies"* is on the ["unsupported list"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html) in the PostgreSQL 11 documentation   ... Thats why i was surprised PostgreSQL supporting it..   *"SQL Server does not support it, nor does Oracle (AFAIK). It's nice to have, though. "*  indeed a RDMS has less work to do when the RDMS could use functional dependency when grouping..

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  However, the correct logic should be to aggregate by user and then assert that the distinct number of roles matches the number of different roles you expect (in this case 2, `ad` and `gm`).

```
SELECT
    u._id, u.firstname, u.lastname, array_agg(r.alias) as roles
FROM users u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN userroles ur ON
    u._id = ur.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN roles r
    ON ur.role_id = r._id
WHERE
    u.firstname = 'Admin' AND
    r.alias IN ('ad', 'gm')
GROUP BY
    u._id
HAVING
    MIN(r.alias) <> MAX(r.alias);
```

Comment: hello @tim-biegeleisen. but (HAVING MIN(r.alias) <> MAX(r.alias)) this wont give the list of user who's first name is Admin and are ether in ad or gm roles

Comment: this worked for me thanks. but the only thing i don't understand why the `HAVING MIN(r.alias) <> MAX(r.alias)` is required it worked without `HAVING`

Comment: @Kapil It would coincidentally work without the `HAVING` clause if all matching users who have the alias `ad` also always have the alias `gm`.  If not, then you would certainly need the `HAVING` clause to get the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't want `LEFT JOIN`, because there are -- by definition of what you want -- going to be matches.

Second, you can handle this by adjusting the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clauses:

```
SELECT u._id, u.firstname, u.lastname, array_agg(r.alias) as roles
FROM users u JOIN
     userroles ur
     ON u._id = ur.user_id JOIN
     roles r
     ON ur.role_id = r._id
WHERE u.firstname = 'Admin' AND
      array['ad', 'gm'] @> array[r.alias]
GROUP BY u._id  -- this is fine assuming `_id` is unique
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

The "2" is the array length of the given array, so you can also parameterize this.

The filtering on `firstname` should go before the aggregation rather than afterwards.

This uses `COUNT(*)` under the assumption that users do not have the same role multiple times.  If that is possible, use `COUNT(DISTINCT r.alias)` instead.

Comment: hi @gordonLinoff sitll having error

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 8:       r.alias) @> '{"ad", "gm"}'
                     ^

Comment: on removing bracket

ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying @> unknown
LINE 8:       r.alias @> '{"ad", "gm"}'

Comment: @Kapil . . . I rewrote the array comparisons the way I would more typically write them (for better or worse).

Comment: exactly what I was looking for was this :-
`SELECT u._id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, array_agg(r.alias) as roles
FROM users u JOIN
     userroles ur
     ON u._id = ur.user_id JOIN
     roles r
     ON ur.role_id = r._id
WHERE u.firstname = 'Admin' AND r.alias IN ('ad','tc','gm','hr') 
GROUP BY u._id`

Answer (score 0):

> For example, Only users who are either admin or hr.

I assume 'ad' is short for admin.  Why does your query not contain 'hr', if that is what you want to query for?

> array_agg(r.alias) @> '{"ad", "gm"}'

This requires both 'ad' and 'gm'.  If you want to require just one of them, use "&&", not "@>".

Comment: if i get multiple r.alias where i want to compare either side of array lies then return the uses eg. in r.alias i get (ad,hr,gm) which is compare with given array (gm,as) hear compare left side into right side and return user list where any one is matched in either side.